# The footer link text overlaps the sidebar, even though the background of the sidebar is on top of the footer

Tags: bug, design, footer, sidebar

The text on the footer overlaps the text on the sidebar:

[image]

This is easier to see if I change the colour of the text:

[image]

It also happens on Stack Overflow:

[image]

But not Ask Ubuntu:

[image]